# XMLwriter add Flush In PHP loops

Tags: php, xmlwriter

I need to create `xml` File using PHP loop and xmlwriter. In action I have two `foreach` loop :

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
foreach ($nav as $k => $v) {
    $writer->openURI($abspath . '/cache/xmls/news-' . $k . '.xml.gz');
    $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $writer->setIndent(4);
    $writer->startElement('urlset');
    $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', $xmlns);
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        $writer->startElement('url');
        $writer->writeElement('loc', SITE . '/' . $v2);
        $writer->writeElement('lastmod', '');
        $writer->writeElement('changefreq', '');
        $writer->writeElement('priority', '');
        $writer->endElement();
        $writer->flush();
    }
    $writer->endElement();
    $writer->endDocument();
    $writer->flush();
    $writer->outputMemory();
}
```

I add `Flush();` for each loop.

1- In action add `flush()` for each loop is TRUE? Or I need To Add One `flush();` for all loops?!

2-I add `openmemory();` This is True After `Fulsh();`?